# Template argument substitution fails and implicit conversion is not done

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

```
#include <type_traits>

template<bool Const>
struct view_tpl {
    using value_type = std::conditional_t<Const, const int, int>;
    value_type* ptr;

    view_tpl() = default;
    view_tpl(const view_tpl<false>& other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }
};

using view = view_tpl<false>;
using const_view = view_tpl<true>;

void read(const const_view& vw) { }

int main() {
    view vw;
    read(vw);
}
```

This code defines a const and a non-const view type, both as aliases to a `view_tpl<Const>` template. It should be such that `view` is implicitly convertible to `const_view`, but not the other way around.

It `Const` is `true`, the defined copy-constructor enables this, and the compiler generates an additional default copy-constructor. If `Const` is `false` the defined copy-constructor replaces the default copy-constructor.

This implicit conversion should happen when `f(vw)` is called.

It works correctly in the above code.

---

But if I add an argument to the templates (`int N`), and turn `f` and the two type aliasses into templates, it no longer works:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N, bool Const>
struct view_tpl {
    using value_type = std::conditional_t<Const, const int, int>;
    value_type* ptr;

    view_tpl() = default;
    view_tpl(const view_tpl<N, false>& other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }
};

template<int N> using view = view_tpl<N, false>;
template<int N> using const_view = view_tpl<N, true>;

template<int N>
void read(const const_view<N>& vw) { }

int main() {
    view<0> vw;
    read(vw);
}
```

Instead of doing the conversion of `view_tpl<0, true>` to `view_tpl<0, false>`, the compiler only tries a direct template substitution and fails:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:20:12: error: no matching function for call to 'read(view<0>&)'
   20 |     read(vw);
      |            ^
main.cpp:16:6: note: candidate: 'template<int N> void read(const_view<N>&)'
   16 | void read(const const_view<N>& vw) { }
      |      ^~~~
main.cpp:16:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:20:12: note:   template argument 'false' does not match 'true'
   20 |     read(vw);
      |            ^
```

Is there a way to make this work without changing too much of the code? (The real code is more complex than this example)

Comment: One possibility, if relevant is inheritance, (`struct view_tpl<N, false> : view_tpl<N, true>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, implicit conversions won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type
>   adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution),
>   which happens later.

You can specify the template argument explicitly to by pass the deduction, then implicit conversion would work fine later. e.g.

```
view<0> vw;
read<0>(vw);
```

Or apply explicit conversion and wrap it into a helper.

```
template<int N>
void read(const view<N>& vw) { read(static_cast<const_view<N>>(vw)); }
```

Answer (score 1):

We could explicitly cast and pass to your `read( const const_view<N> )` function by overloading for both types.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N, bool Const>
struct view_tpl {
    using value_type = std::conditional_t<Const, const int, int>;
    value_type* ptr;

    view_tpl() = default;
    view_tpl(const view_tpl<N, false>& other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }
};

template<int N> using view = view_tpl<N, false>;
template<int N> using const_view = view_tpl<N, true>;

template<int N>
void read( const const_view<N>& vw )
{
    // 
}

template<int N>
void read( const view<N>& vw )
{
    const_view<N> vw_converted { vw };

    read( vw_converted );
}

int main() {
    view<0> vw;
    const_view<1> cvw;
    read(vw);
    read(cvw);
}
```

[run online](https://onlinegdb.com/HJg2zaXNL)

Or if you don't mind extra copy for `const_view`

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N, bool Const>
struct view_tpl {
    using value_type = std::conditional_t<Const, const int, int>;
    value_type* ptr;

    view_tpl() = default;
    view_tpl(const view_tpl<N, false>& other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }
};

template<int N> using view = view_tpl<N, false>;
template<int N> using const_view = view_tpl<N, true>;

template<int N, bool Const>
void read(const view_tpl<N,Const>& vw ) {
    view_tpl<N,true> inst { vw }; // Now it is const
                                  // But one extra copy for const_view
}

int main() {
    view<0> vw;
    const_view<1> cvw;
    read(vw);
    read(cvw);
}
```

[run online](https://onlinegdb.com/ryDg7pX4U)